# Simplify trigonometric representations of spin-weighted spherical harmonics with SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I have implemented the spin-weighted spherical harmonics (SWSH) in Sympy, which give the correct expressions but in an un-simplified form.

For example, the SWSH with spin=0 l=1 m=0 has in it the expression

```
(1/tan(0.5*th))**2.0 - 1
```

which can be simplified easily in for example Mathematica to

```
cos(th)*csc(0.5*th)**2
```

I have tried the following to reproduce this simplification using Sympy's functions:

- `simplify` and `trigsimp`
- `expr.rewrite(exp).simplify().expand().rewrite(sin).simplify()`
- `expr.rewrite(exp).simplify().expand().rewrite(cos).simplify()`

but unfortunately it just doesn't want to simplify, and I cannot see any other way.

At the end of the day I am writing a function as a sum of these things, and Ineed to integrate the result. The problem is because these expressions do not simplify, the resulting integrand is long and complicated and the integration takes forever.

I am not able to hardcode the expressions for the SWSH as there are too many that I am using, hence I must calculate them.

Thus if somebody could lead me toward a method of using built-in Sympy simplification functions to simplify this expression that would be great. Hopefully the method will also simplify other SWSH too.

Comment: I don't consider the second expression simpler than the first one. There's a good chance integration fails because you have floating point numbers in the exponents. Those are to be avoided in SymPy whenever possible. E.g., `expr = (1/tan(th/2))**2 - 1` is a way to not create them: avoid the division of one Python int by another.  [More on SymPy numbers](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#python-numbers-vs-sympy-numbers).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately for my application I need to reduce the expression to that form, as it is one term not two, which makes a difference later. How do you suggest to create powers? In Sympy tutorial it explicitly has cos(x)**2 as an example.

Comment: `cos(x)**2` is fine. `cos(x)**2.0` is problematic for SymPy

Answer (score 0):

The module [`fu.py`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/simplify/fu.py) contains several specialized trigonometric transformation procedures. For example, TR2 converts tan-cot to sin-cos.

```
from sympy.simplify.fu import *
expr = (1/tan(th/2))**2 - 1      # no floats please, we are symbolic
e2 = TR2(expr).trigsimp()
```

Now e2 is `-2*cos(th)/(cos(th) - 1)`. It's no longer the sum of two terms, and there is `cos(th)` in it; but the other thing is not yet what you wanted. It turns out to be hard to convince SymPy to turn `1-cos(th)` into `2*sin(th/2)**2` --- perhaps unsurprisingly, since the latter does look more complicated. I got it with

```
e3 = TR7(TR5(TR6(TR11(e2.subs(th, 2*th))))).subs(th, th/2)
```

which results in `cos(th)/sin(th/2)**2`. The logic is:

1. Double the angle, get `-2*cos(2*th)/(cos(2*th) - 1)`
2. TR11 - reduce double angles, get `-2*(-sin(th)**2 + cos(th)**2)/(-sin(th)**2 + cos(th)**2 - 1)`
3. TR6 - powers of cos to powers of sin, get `(-2*sin(th)**2 + 1)/sin(th)**2`. This achieved the desired form of the denominator; it remains to undo the collateral damage to the numerator.
4. TR5 - powers of sin to powers of cos, get `(2*cos(th)**2 - 1)/sin(th)**2`
5. TR7 - reduce cos power (increase angle), get `cos(2*th)/sin(th)**2`
6. Half the angle, get `cos(th)/sin(th/2)**2`

The steps 4, 5, 6 are essentially the inverses of 3, 2, 1.